# Android successful JSON response but response.isSuccess() is not true

Tags: android, json, gson, instagram

I am finally getting a response from the Instagram's API for the access token.

```
final Call<TokenResponse> accessToken =  ServiceManager.createTokenService().getAccessToken(request);
accessToken.enqueue(new Callback<TokenResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<TokenResponse> call, Response<TokenResponse> response) {
        mtext.setText("hello");
      }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<TokenResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        mtext.setText("failure");
    }
});
```

However when I check if response.isSuccess() it fails? I don't understand this.

Also, I am using Retrofit 2 and I have imported the Gson should it automatically map the data right?

Comment: TokenRequest request = new TokenRequest();
        request.setClient_id(Constants.CLIENT_ID);
        request.setClient_secret(Constants.CLIENT_SECRET);
        request.setGrant_type(Constants.AUTORISATION_CODE);
        request.setRedirect_uri(Constants.REDIRECT_URI);
        request.setCode(code);

Comment: I logged around a little bit and the error keeps saying you must provide client_id where as Im clearly putting that in. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In retrofit 2, `onFailure` only invoked when a network or unexpected exception occurred during the HTTP request.

`response.isSuccess()` when the http status is 2xx or 3xx it will return true, or else, it will return false.

So, when isSuccess is true, you can use right data model to map the json. You can define a common error model to map the json when isSuccess is false.

[EDIT]Add some smaple code snippet that I used retrofit2 in my project, hope this will help you.

```
@Override public void onResponse(Response<T> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
  onNetworkRequestFinished();
  if (response.isSuccess()) {
    onSuccess(response.body());
  } else {
    onFailed(response, retrofit);
  }
 }


@Override public void onSuccess(SignupResponse signupResponse) {
  ((JFragmentActivity) context).dialogHelper.dismissProgressDialog();
  sharedPreferenceHelper.saveLoginName(context, userName); 
  doAfterSignin(context, signupResponse);
}


public void onFailed(Response response, Retrofit retrofit) {
  Converter<ResponseBody, JErrorReponse> errorConverter =
    retrofit.responseConverter(JErrorReponse.class, new Annotation[0]);

    try {
      JErrorReponse error = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());
      if (error != null) {
        JToast.toastLong(error.msg);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

the JErrorResponse.java

```
public class JErrorReponse implements Serializable {
  public int status;
  public String msg;
  public Object err;
}
```

SignupResponse.java

```
public class SignupResponse extends BaseResponse {

  public UserLoginData data;
}
```

UserLoginData.java

```
public class UserLoginData implements Serializable {
  @SerializedName("u_id") public int uId;

  @SerializedName("username") public String userName;

  public String icon;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 2xx or 3xx and how can I achieve that?

Comment: Also, I have made the relevant pojo classes so once I do get true for onsuccess, how can map it onto those classes? I thought that retrofit 2+gson would do that automatically.

Comment: @Hasan Nagaria 
#1 When your api response with http status code 2xx or 3xx, such as 200 or 304, response.isSuccess() will be return true.

#2 You are right, retrofit will map the pojo class with json automatically.

Comment: You are correct, I just checked and im getting 4xx which means Im doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, 4xx means something incorrect in you request parameter, header, etc., you will get the callback still on ```onResponse(Response<T> response, Retrofit retrofit) ```, but the response.isScucess will return false in this case. BTW, I just added some more sample code.

Comment: This looks good, ill definitely use this in my code as well! Thanks

Comment: Please see my additional post, I am having a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261661/null-responses-using-retrofit-calls