# Null Responses Using Retrofit Calls

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, flickr

I am using `Retrofit` to make a call to the `FlickR API` and I have successfully set up all of my model classes.

I am trying to access the m_url values for each Photo in the Photos array. Unfortunately, the Retrofit response is generating a null object:

I am using Retrofit and the FlickRAPI to query the FlickR database for photos.

**Model:**

**Photos:**

```
public class Photos {

@SerializedName("page")
@Expose
private int page;
@SerializedName("pages")
@Expose
private int pages;
@SerializedName("perpage")
@Expose
private int perpage;
@SerializedName("total")
@Expose
private String total;
@SerializedName("photo")
@Expose
private List<Photo> photo = new ArrayList<Photo>();

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The page
 */
public int getPage() {
    return page;
}

/**
 *
 * @param page
 *     The page
 */
public void setPage(int page) {
    this.page = page;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The pages
 */
public int getPages() {
    return pages;
}

/**
 *
 * @param pages
 *     The pages
 */
public void setPages(int pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The perpage
 */
public int getPerpage() {
    return perpage;
}

/**
 *
 * @param perpage
 *     The perpage
 */
public void setPerpage(int perpage) {
    this.perpage = perpage;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The total
 */
public String getTotal() {
    return total;
}

/**
 *
 * @param total
 *     The total
 */
public void setTotal(String total) {
    this.total = total;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The photo
 */
public List<Photo> getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

/**
 *
 * @param photo
 *     The photo
 */
public void setPhoto(List<Photo> photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
  }

}
```

**Photo:**

```
public class Photo {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("owner")
@Expose
private String owner;
@SerializedName("secret")
@Expose
private String secret;
@SerializedName("server")
@Expose
private String server;
@SerializedName("farm")
@Expose
private int farm;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("ispublic")
@Expose
private int ispublic;
@SerializedName("isfriend")
@Expose
private int isfriend;
@SerializedName("isfamily")
@Expose
private int isfamily;
@SerializedName("url_m")
@Expose
private String urlM;
@SerializedName("height_m")
@Expose
private String heightM;
@SerializedName("width_m")
@Expose
private String widthM;

/**
 * @return The id
 */
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id The id
 */
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return The owner
 */
public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

/**
 * @param owner The owner
 */
public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}

/**
 * @return The secret
 */
public String getSecret() {
    return secret;
}

/**
 * @param secret The secret
 */
public void setSecret(String secret) {
    this.secret = secret;
}

/**
 * @return The server
 */
public String getServer() {
    return server;
}

/**
 * @param server The server
 */
public void setServer(String server) {
    this.server = server;
}

/**
 * @return The farm
 */
public int getFarm() {
    return farm;
}

/**
 * @param farm The farm
 */
public void setFarm(int farm) {
    this.farm = farm;
}

/**
 * @return The title
 */
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

/**
 * @param title The title
 */
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

/**
 * @return The ispublic
 */
public int getIspublic() {
    return ispublic;
}

/**
 * @param ispublic The ispublic
 */
public void setIspublic(int ispublic) {
    this.ispublic = ispublic;
}

/**
 * @return The isfriend
 */
public int getIsfriend() {
    return isfriend;
}

/**
 * @param isfriend The isfriend
 */
public void setIsfriend(int isfriend) {
    this.isfriend = isfriend;
}

/**
 * @return The isfamily
 */
public int getIsfamily() {
    return isfamily;
}

/**
 * @param isfamily The isfamily
 */
public void setIsfamily(int isfamily) {
    this.isfamily = isfamily;
}

/**
 * @return The urlM
 */
public String getUrlM() {
    return urlM;
}

/**
 * @param urlM The url_m
 */
public void setUrlM(String urlM) {
    this.urlM = urlM;
}

/**
 * @return The heightM
 */
public String getHeightM() {
    return heightM;
}

/**
 * @param heightM The height_m
 */
public void setHeightM(String heightM) {
    this.heightM = heightM;
}

/**
 * @return The widthM
 */
public String getWidthM() {
    return widthM;
}

/**
 * @param widthM The width_m
 */
public void setWidthM(String widthM) {
    this.widthM = widthM;
}

}
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{
  photos: {
  page: 1,
  pages: 3683,
  perpage: 100,
  total: "368270",
  photo: [
       {
       id: "29264707352",
       owner: "84316756@N02",
       secret: "9ed355a86e",
       server: "8603",
       farm: 9,
       title: "Tercer Patio de los Claustros de la Compañía/ Arequipa",
       ispublic: 1,
       isfriend: 0,
       isfamily: 0,
       url_m:          "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8603/29264707352_9ed355a86e.jpg",
       height_m: "500",
       width_m: "333"
          },
        {
        id: "29339070436",
        owner: "146617764@N02",
        secret: "b52f1e9914",
        server: "8509",
        farm: 9,
        title: "2016-04-17 09.24.07",
        ispublic: 1,
        isfriend: 0,
        isfamily: 0,
        url_m: "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8509/29339070436_b52f1e9914.jpg",
        height_m: "281",
        width_m: "500"
       },
```

Ultimately, I want to get the url_m of the photo, here is my code:

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Photos>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Photos> call, Response<Photos> response) {
                    Log.v("RESPONSE_CALLED", "ON_RESPONSE_CALLED");
                    List<Photo> photoResults = response.body().getPhoto();
                    Log.v("PHOTO_TOTALS", response.body().getTotal());
                    for (Photo photo : photoResults) {
                        Log.v("PHOTO_URL:", photo.getUrlM()
                        );
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Photos> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

Right now, I am receiving a NullPointer:

```
08-31 21:31:39.425 2526-2526/com.troychuinard.flickr_test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.troychuinard.flickr_test, PID: 2526
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
at com.troychuinard.flickr_test.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:65)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: so what happens why you do for example `Log.v("PHOTO_URL:", photo.getTitle());`

Comment: BTW where are you the json => pojo conversion?

Comment: I just mapped it myself, does it look wrong?

Comment: It actually never logs the "PHOTO_URL," so the for loop is not being triggered

Comment: well if it is missing ...

Comment: which line is line 65?

Comment: Line 65:                     Log.v("PHOTO_TOTALS", response.body().getTotal());

Comment: so lets close this question again.  Debug your code, learn how to deal with NPE.  I have no idea what ` response.body()` is doing, but it returns a null

Comment: or maybe you mean `response.body().getPhoto().getTotal ()` ?

Comment: BTW, learn to use a debugger, step though your code and examine the values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122350/discussion-between-tccpg288-and-scary-wombat).